# How to mask an imported image as a plane?

Tags: masking

I just want to make a mask for an image as plane like in Gimp or any Image Editor.

I have a transparent drawing and I want to "fill" some parts of that drawing with other images as planes and other parts fills with materials.

I have a video that shows an example of what I want to do (of somebody doing it in After Effects): https://youtu.be/wSeOrwoe5r8

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome! I saw your video, but still can't understand what you're trying to achieve. Try adding more detail, perhaps an image (use the question editor tool) that helps others to understand at least your current setup. Is it just a setup to render a still image or you wish some kind of animated effect as in the linked video?

Comment: Use the alpha channel of the image to control the mix of shaders or images. Read this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do, is using the image that you want to be filled with the transparent image, and convert it with a Color Ramp. This will work if you have a lot of contrast in that image. Here the Node setup: [image: Node setup.]